# Creating div slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well im trying to create a div slide that would show 3 divs at one time and after sometime ie 5 seconds 3 new divs would be displayed.

Problem: I have seen several things built for images but nothing for div's.

**HTML**

```
<div class="showcaseDetails">
    <a href="" class="showcaseLink">
        <img src="555.jpg" class="showcasePhoto">
    </a>
    <div class="showcaseAddress">555 example rd</div>
    <div class="showcaseCityStateZip">exampletown</div>
    <div class="showcasePrice">$555,000</div>
    <br>
</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EAvf2/)

Comment: You should provide your JS code attempt. At least try and create it yourself instead of just asking for a script.

Comment: Im not asking for a script silly...Im looking for some prebuilt solution like the answer below :) happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very good question as there is no issue/problem.

But I will recommend

## [Swipe](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe)

Comment: +1 for answering on poorly asked question (Y)

Comment: You seemed to know exactly what i was look for therefore my question portrayed the problem well enough to get the response I was looking for :) muhahahaha

Comment: That doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: "good" is all in eye of the observer my friend...Its the perfect question to me...got 1 answer and it was the answer i was looking for :)